# fetch the json value and assign in json using node js / javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

```js
let arrayId={
  "za": {
    "gasjxhj6782": {
      "value": "gasjxhj6782",
      "access": "Available at some point"
    },
    "vghasj56728": {
      "value": "vghasj56728",
      "access": "Access denied"
    },
    "ldghjd67821": {
      "value": "ldghjd67821",
      "access": "Admin role"
    }
  },
  "cn": {
    "hjaks7812": {
      "value": "hjaks7812",
      "access": "Available at some point"
    },
    "78912ashm": {
      "value": "78912ashm",
      "access": "Access denied"
    }
  },
  "tw": {
    "78912ashm": {
      "value": "78912ashm",
      "access": "Access denied"
    }
  }
};

let obj="hjaks7812";

function blockAccess(obj) {
  if (obj in arrayId) {
    attrs = {
      "type": "Access permission",
      "entry-level-id": "",
      "key": "",
      "access": "",
    };
  }
  console.log(attrs);
}
```

This is my function I want to check the value of `obj` present in `arrayId` and assign the value

for eg `obj` is `hjaks7812` I want to check it present at which level of `arrayId`

and make my expectation output as this if the value is `hjaks7812`

```
{
  "type": "Access permission",
  "entry-level-id": "hjaks7812",
  "key": "cn",
  "access": "Available at some point",
}
```

but value of obj get changed maybe it can be `gasjxhj6782` or any thing then it should take that value if the obj value is like this `gasjxhj6782` then expectation value will be like this

```
{
  "type": "Access permission",
  "entry-level-id": "gasjxhj6782",
  "key": "za",
  "access": "Available at some point",
}
```

as I want to check obj at which level and assign that value here `za cn tw` get changed everytime as this is user define so I want to check at which level the value which is assign in obj is present and fill that attr

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how you are calling `blockAccess`. Note that `entryId` is undefined as your code is written (`arrayId` !== `entryId`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this approach with entries and double loop

```js
let arrayId = {
  "za": {
    "gasjxhj6782": {
      "value": "gasjxhj6782",
      "access": "Available at some point"
    },
    "vghasj56728": {
      "value": "vghasj56728",
      "access": "Access denied"
    },
    "ldghjd67821": {
      "value": "ldghjd67821",
      "access": "Admin role"
    }
  },
  "cn": {
    "hjaks7812": {
      "value": "hjaks7812",
      "access": "Available at some point"
    },
    "78912ashm": {
      "value": "78912ashm",
      "access": "Access denied"
    }
  },
  "tw": {
    "78912ashm": {
      "value": "78912ashm",
      "access": "Access denied"
    }
  }
};

function blockAccess(key) {
  for (const [arrayKey, arrayValue] of Object.entries(arrayId)) {
    for (const [accessKey, accessValue] of Object.entries(arrayValue)) {
      if (accessKey === key) {
        return {
          "type": "Access permission",
          "entry-level-id": accessKey,
          "key": arrayKey,
          "access": accessValue.access,
        };
      }
    }
  }
  return 'Not found'
}

console.log(blockAccess("hjaks7812"))
console.log(blockAccess("gasjxhj6782"))
console.log(blockAccess("testing")) //Not found if the key is not in your data
```

Comment: This works, If depth is variable make it a recursive function.